# Formulário de Login AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Galera, estou iniciando do AngularJS e estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Tenho uma página HTML index.html nela eu carrego todos os scripts do projeto e inicializo o app. Dentro dela tbem tenho um ng-view onde são carregas as minhas outras views que são as minhas páginas internas.

Fato é que minha aplicação sempre é iniciada pelo index.html, e agora eu quero montar uma página de login que será independente e que deve ser iniciada antes no index.html. Somente quando o usuário passar pelo login com sucesso é que a index.html será carregada.

Hoje se eu adiciono o login como uma view normal ele abre dentro da minha página index no ng-view e não é o que eu quero.

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi. Sua página de login é uma página completa, e não uma view. Você quer ir para ela quando o usuário clickar em um botão (por exemplo), substituindo toda a página `index.html` por ela? E esta com dúvidas em como fazer isso no Angular?

Comment: Não quando clique em um botão. Eu quero que a primeira página seja o login, e caso ele passe ai sim ele terá acesso a index.html (que é uma página completa que carregas as views dentro dela mesma)

Comment: Crie uma div fora do ng-view associada ao controller de login. Essa div tever ficar sobre todos os outros elementos da página, tampando tudo. Mas não é nem um pouco recomendável, já que com comandos no console do browser é possível "pular" o login e acessar o resto da página.

Comment: Alguma retorno quanto a isso ? também tenho duvidas.

Comment: Você pode também ter um modulo para o login e outro para a aplicação, dessa forma facilitaria ter uma página de login com uma cara diferente da página da aplicação.